# Formatting the horizontal axis (category groups) in an SSRS chart

Tags: sql-server, sql, reporting-services

I have 2 category groups in my SSRS chart. One is "short weekday name", the other is "hours". I want the graph to show hour-by-hour change, but I want only the "short weekday name" to be shown in the horizontal axis. Is this possible?

In advance, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you have the "hours" category selected, look to the Properties pane and under Other you will see Label.  Remove its contents.

Incidently, "short weekday name" should be the first category (that is, on the left).

Hope this helps!